# How can I measure activation level of each nodes when predict using trained model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm interesting in which nodes are activated and how much strongly activated when some input is entered to trained model.

The picture as bellow shows what I want to get from model.
(I want to know the degree of activation in every nodes)

As I know there are some techniques to visualize what the nodes(or filter) are paying attention to. (especially in CNN)

**Is there any good way to measure how active each nodes are?**

I usually using Keras. But pyTorch is ok too.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **activation map / grad cam** ..., you can get a look at : https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/ and https://keras.io/examples/vision/visualizing_what_convnets_learn/

You can also try **keract** : https://github.com/philipperemy/keract

There are others github repository on the subject on explainability in the AI field, such as : https://github.com/XAI-ANITI/ethik

Alternatively, you can do it yourself it both keras and pytorch, for example by registering a hook in pytorch :

```py
def get_feat_vector(self, img, model):
        with torch.no_grad():
            my_output = None
            
            def my_hook(module_, input_, output_):
                nonlocal my_output
                my_output = output_
            
            a_hook = model.layers[0].register_forward_hook(my_hook)        
            model(img)
            a_hook.remove()
            return my_output

...

for element in val_dataloader:
    model.eval()
    feature_vect = get_feat_vector(element[0].float().cuda(), model)
```